# Should there be a new tag for Airman Certification Standards?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have an "Airman-certification" tag, but with the new distinction of the old "Practical Test Standards" currently being phased out, and the new "Airman Certification Standards" which seem to be raising more than a few questions in the aviation community an "Airman-Certification-Standards" tag would seem to me as a good idea because now we really have three topics:

1. General certification questions about experience, training, and flight time totals to qualify and other such bureaucratically-based questions.
2. Questions about the PTS.
3. Questions about the ACS.

Should we have a new tag for this?

Comment: Considering that we've never had a PTS tag, is an ACS one really needed?

Comment: @Pondlife The difference is now there is a distinction among three concepts rather than two.  I am asking this to come up with an idea to help a person who may be searching for questions regarding the changes being implemented because this is kind of a big deal for those under FAA.  You do have a point though.  I was kind of surprised when I checked the tags before asking this question and saw that we did not have a PTS tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we need a tag specifically for the ACS:

1. The PTS previously defined the standards for airman certification by the FAA (or more accurately, how you were tested to ensure you met those standards).
2. The ACS replaces the PTS, so airman certification testing under the FAA's jurisdiction will adhere to the ACS.
3. [airman-certification-standards](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airman-certification-standards) as a tag is inherently meta: It requires another tag (FAA, EASA, etc.) to clarify precisely whose standards we're taking about. The fact that the FAA named their standard like they are the only group promulgating a standard notwithstanding, other countries/jurisdictions may in fact vary significantly from the FAA ACS.

Comment: I would add that the suggested tag name is too long anyway. As far as coming up with something else, I believe that someone asking a question in this area isn't going to care if it's a standards question or not. They just want to know how it affects them getting their new certificate, and I believe that the more general tag works as-is.